# Why BitBucket ignores previous PR when a new PR is merged on the same branch?

Tags: git, bitbucket, pull-request

**TD;DR:** What really happens with code from past PR's that didn't were approved before newer ones were?

I have several PR's with conflict trying to merge with my main branch called "develop":

[image]

On "develop", I have commits c1, c2, c3 and so on. Consider my PR from feature 1 resulted into conflict at files A and B. My feature 2 resulted into conflict at only file C. Let's suppose, to fix feature 2 PR, the developer created a new branch from develop, pulled feature 2 content and submitted into a PR too (let's call it PR 3) with the correct decision from A and B, besides all other feature 2 files. When this newer PR 3 was approved, feature 2 PR was automatically approved too. What happens to conflicted PR from feature 1?

It cannot be merged anymore into a past commit besides HEAD from develop. It's source code was not added on feature 2 PR neither on PR 3. With some personal experience, I thought in that situation feature 1 PR appears as MERGED but actually not even a single file was present at C3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose a little confusion in your question.

First your picture is wrong, a pull request ask to merge a **branch** with an other here the develop branch :

=>So both branch should point to a "virtual" c5 resulting of c4 merged with feature1 or c4 merged with feature2

Secondly, I suppose you are talking about **merge** instead of approve. Bitbucket doesn't approve anything by itself it would be awesome ;)

So lets recap the real diagram is :

```
  A---------B---------C Feature1 (PR1)
 /                      \
c0--C1---C2---C2---C3---C4---(C5) develop
           \                /
             E---F-----------Feature2 (PR2)
                  \       /
                    G---- PR3
```

So when you hit merge on PR3 You create a commit C5 containing E, F, G. So in the develop branch you have E,F correspond to Feature2 PR2 + G PR3 This is why bitbucket can automaticaly tell PR2 is merge. *Depending on your version but if you read carefully PR2, bitbucket will tell you that is merge with PR3.*

So What happen to PR1 ? Now you are in this situation :

```
  A---------------B-------------C Feature1 (PR1)
 /                                \                 
c0--C1---C2---C2---C3---C4---C5---(C6) develop
```

Maybe all conflict are gone maybe not but bitbucket won't ignore/merge anything for you.